# Sorting a list of the list with loop

Tags: python, list, sorting, linked-list

```
import io
f = io.StringIO('''130,266.07
46,174.14
169,187.01
179,488.69
53,401.53
128,106.88
97,398.33
152,493.87
20,205.43
94,248.14''')
x=0
y=0
for line in f:
    x +=1
alist=x*[0]
for i in range(x):
    alist[i]=[]
f.close()
g= io.StringIO('''130,266.07
46,174.14
169,187.01
179,488.69
53,401.53
128,106.88
97,398.33
152,493.87
20,205.43
94,248.14''')
for line in g:
    s=line.split(",")
    alist[y].append(int(s[0]))
    alist[y].append(float(s[1]))
    y +=1
def printlist():
    h=0
    while h <x  :
        blist=alist[h]
        h += 1
        print(str(blist[0])+" Kms, "+",$"+str(blist[1]))
for index in range(x):
    value=alist[index]
    j = index-1
    while j>=0:
        if value < alist[j]:
            alist[j+1] = alist[j]
            alist[j] = value
            j -= 1
        else:
            break
printlist()
```

The problem is that the input values would be something like this `[[a, b], [c, d], ...]`, and right now it would sort it according to the first element (for example, `a` or `c`) instead of second one (`b` and `d`) and I need to sort it by _the second value. Right not the out put would be sorted data regard to the first element if each list, however I need it to be sorted regard to the second value of each list which is also a float and can't be compared a integer. Thanks

Comment: could you provide the desired output for this input ?

Comment: Is this python2? Because otherwise comparing lists will throw errors.

Comment: the out put I'm looking for a sorted by the second element but what I get is sorted by the first element.

Comment: no I'm using python 3.5

Comment: `if value[1] < alist[j][1]` or even better (tiebreaker) `value[::-1] < alist[j][::-1]`

Comment: @COLDSPEED: comparing lists works whatever python version...

Comment: [mcve] please. What is `x` ? your code doesn't work as is.

Comment: may I suggest: `sorted(a_list,key = lambda x:x[1])` ?

Comment: @SinaFasahat Why do you not just use the built-in functionality for sorting? like `sorted(list)` or `list.sort()`

Comment: @an-François Fabre I put in the whole code

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre @ Ev. Kou  Yes but I'm not allowed to do such a thing and I was told to di it with loops

Comment: edited question doesn't deserve so much downvotes. [mcve] works.

Answer (score 0):

As I first suggested in comments, you're comparing the list, thus using natural comparison for lists:

```
if value < alist[j]:
```

this compares first elements, then seconds if firsts are equal (and if there are second(s) elements), and so on.

What you need is to compare with the second element of the sublists only, regardless of the first one:

```
if value[1] < alist[j][1]:
```

If you want a tiebreaker in case values are equal, consider comparing *reversed* lists:

```
if value[::-1] < alist[j][::-1]:
```

of course, in the end, nothing beats python built-in sort:

```
sorted(a_list,key = lambda x:x[1])
```

with tiebreaker:

```
sorted(a_list,key = lambda x:x[::-1])
```

Anyway, the output, it seems that sorting by cost has worked:

```
128 Kms, ,$106.88
46 Kms, ,$174.14
169 Kms, ,$187.01
20 Kms, ,$205.43
94 Kms, ,$248.14
130 Kms, ,$266.07
97 Kms, ,$398.33
53 Kms, ,$401.53
179 Kms, ,$488.69
152 Kms, ,$493.87
```